# Mount/Render a React component manually using JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, coffeescript, react-rails

I am trying to use the react-rails with the kaminari gem.
below piece of code is responsible for creating the Admins page with pagination, paginate being a kaminari method:

```
#app/views/dashboard/admins/_admins.html.erb
<div id="admins_component">
  <%= react_component 'Admins', {data: admins} %>
</div>
<%= paginate admins, :remote => true %>
```

on firing request with remote=true, this whole stuff is repainted, the response being generate through the following code:

```
#app/views/dashboard/admins/index.js.erb
<% if @admins.present? %>
$("#admin_wrapper").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'admins', locals: { admins: @admins } ) %>");
React.render("Admins", "#admins_component"); //How to make this work???
<% end %>
```

After the ajax request, the response is correctly generated and the ReactComponent is also being created in the HTML of the page as follows:

```
<div data-react-class="Admins" data-react-props="{"data":[{"id":26,"email":"okokoko@kok.com","created_at":"2016-03-16T09:10:48.220Z","updated_at":"2016-03-16T09:10:48.220Z"}]}"></div>
```

But the problem is that the component is not rendered/mounted. I tried mounting the component manually through console, but I am not sure if I was doing it correctly or not.

Moreover, the react extension in chrome displays the previous state of the Admin component, after the request for next page is fired:
[image]

Aim is to replace the html of the red-box below, on clicking the pagination link:[image]

When I run Admin.prototype in console before/after clicking on the pagination link, I get the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`react-rails` includes some helpers for mounting components based on `data-react-class` and `data-react-props` attributes. The gem uses these helpers for mounting components and you can call them yourself, too.

You should remove this line:

```
React.render("Admins", "#admins_component"); //How to make this work???
```

And replace it with:

```
// Find any divs with `data-react-class` and mount them 
ReactRailsUJS.mountComponents()
```

It's ok to call that function anytime. Even if a component is already mounted, it will re-render it but not mess anything up!

You can see all of `react-rails`'s helpers in the `react_ujs*` files here:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/tree/master/lib/assets/javascripts

Comment: But, if I have 2 components and I want to selectively render only one of them on the basis of id/class, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can scope `mountComponents` by a selector, eg `ReactRailsUJS.mountComponents("#admins_components")`